# How to integrate cloudbuild (GCP) with CodeCommit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build, aws-codecommit

I have my source code in code commit and my new client is with GCP. They wanted to connect code-commit from google cloud-build, is there any option for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that GCP and AWS are competitor cloud providers I would say that you will not find a way to trigger Google Cloud Build from AWS CodeCommit, which is what I believe you mean with "integrate" both products.

What I would do in your scenario is replicate you CodeCommit repository in it's equivalent in GCP, which is [Google Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories). You can find a tutorial for how to setup
Build Triggers from Cloud Source Repositories in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers). Another option is pushing a container ready to be deployed into Cloud Registry and deploying that instead, you can follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#containerizing) for that.

Comment: No, AWS is parent actually (where our all project lies) and the GCP is a new client. So  we cannot move the entire code their too, either a code replciation issue will come. I think we might think of building the image in aws and then pushing to Google Cloud Registry ? What about that ?

Comment: Yes, if you have a container all setup and ready to be launched I believe it could work.

Comment: @JithinKumarS I edited the answer to contain the approach you proposed.